# Intellij - cannot resolve symbol dbutils, apache

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, databricks

I imported scala notebook from databricks into Intellij but for below lines

dbutils.widgets.text("sourcePath", "xyz", "Source Path:");
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;

I'm getting error as cannot resolve symbol dbutils and cannot resolve symbol apache for second line.

Could you please advise what might be issue?

Comment: You're probably missing some dependencies.

Comment: how can we add these dbutils and apache dependencies?

Comment: @SyedMohammedMehdi, I have not tried it, but maybe this documentation might help ?https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html#intellij-idea